# Best Browser Control to view SSRS Reports?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, reporting-services

I'm working on a c# desktop project where one of the modules in the program for displaying SSRS Reports.

The flow is as follows:
User presses a button > Presented with a form to enter a description & a URL. These two values are then written to a text file.
User then presses a second button, a new form opens with a WebKit.Net browser. At the top of the page is a dropdown containing the descriptions, the user selects the description and presses ok. -This then navigates to the url associated to that description.

This all works fine with websites such as http://www.google.com

However, the moment I enter an SSRS Report Manager URL, it falls over. -IE)It no longer navigates, no errors, no nothing. Just a white page.

My SSRS URL is: `http://server:8080/Reports_SQLEXPRESS/Pages/Folder.aspx`

I understand that Webkit.Net is a chrome wrapper, so I have tested my Report Manager in Chrome and it works fine. (Some limited functionality I admit, but enough for what I need to do.)

I have also tried using the default WebBrowser control included in Visual Studio - This works, however when I go to download the PDF Report I get a script error because of the URL:

```
Http://username:password@UrlGoesHere
```

However that is the only way I can access the Report Server through my program, as it uses the current users Windows Credentials. -The users who will use my app don't have access to the report Manager, thus the need for my url to include my credentials.

**Is there a suitable wrapper that I can use for SSRS?** I need to be able to run reports, limit navigation only to the URL loaded and have the ability to download reports.
-I do not have the skills to be able to write my own.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Address = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(Address);
        this.webKitBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri(Address, System.UriKind.Absolute);

    }
```

I have also tried using the:`WebBrowser1.Navigate();` function -It still does not load the report server page.

Comment: It doesn't need them, I'm testing on my Home RS when its actually for a Work RS which does need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, looks like the best thing to use isn't a browser after all!

For those who have stumbled across this with similar issues to me: ReportViewer is the answer!

Its a pre-included control with VS, (However you may have to update the assembly to version 11, or the control will be added as a component for some strange reason... Details on how to do so can be found [Here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?717175-How-to-use-Report-Viewer-with-Visual-Studio-2012-Express))

This control is exactly the same as the report viewer used in SQL Report Manager itself. Plus you can set credentials without having to worry about the user seeing them!